# How to set a class visible from another?

Tags: java, class, jcomponent

I have a drawing board with some circles, triangles and rectangles. I want to be able to set them visible and not.

The classes name are `Circle`, `Triangle`, `Rectangle` and is extending `JComponent`, and they all have an unique color.

Someone suggested `Triangle c = null;` and then use `c.setVisible(true)` to make it visible - but it only gives `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException` referring to `c.setVisible(true)`

Anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Don't set it to null - just call setVisible() with true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use :

`Triangle c = new Triangle();`

`c.setVisible(true);`

Instead of **null**

Reference variables with **null** value will always give you NullPointerException when you call it with dot(.) operator.